# How to detect if the web application is deployed as a virtual directory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, relative-path, virtual-directory

My MVC3 Web Application is not always deployed as a site in IIS, so I need to detect if it has been deployed as a virtual directory or application in order to handle the path string.

for example, if the site is deployed as a website under IIS root, if i write:

\ABC\test.txt

this is fine, the request goes to `http://somehost/ABC/test.txt`

but if the site is deployed as a virtual directory or application under an existing site in IIS, for example:

```
http://somehost/mymvcapp/
```

then, the request for "\ABC\test.txt" will not be correct.

I understand that write "~\App_Data\test.txt" will solve the problem, but "~\" can only be processed by the server in current web context. Sometime I need to do some process on the file in other layers, they can't touch web context.

So I need to detect if the application has been deployed as a virtual directory. and find the actual physical path to the file. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: When you say "do some process on the file in other layers," what exactly do you mean? You need to access to something relating to the application in order to learn anything about it. Do you mean you're spawning a thread that isn't running in the context of a web request? Or a whole different process?

Comment: @Jacob i didt make it clear. All I need is to pass the physical file path to the business layer. because the biz layer is not allowed to using system.web. and I found that if i use Server.MapPath(@"\...."), the result will be wrong if the website is deployed as an application or virtual directory attached to an existing site in IIS. Server.MapPath(@"~\....") is correct, but there's some satuations i can't write "~\" instead of "\".

Comment: @Jacob the css guy write something like background-image: url("/Images/...") and there are many defects like this in the UI layer. It's difficult to describe the situation, i can't just insert a "~" to the path. All I need is to get the absolute path of the current site path. Then I can combine the path myself. I think I can get Server.MapPath(@"~\") first and try to combine the path. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your business layer can't reference `System.Web`, then you have to expect that it can't detect any information about your web application period. This means that the code should not be expected to resolve file paths within your site.

What you could do instead is have an intermediate configuration layer that the application initializes and the business layer can consume. For example, given this interface which is accessible to both layers:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    string DataFolder { get; }
}
```

... you could have code in your `Global.asax` that initializes it:

```
IConfiguration config = ...;
...
config.DataFolder = this.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
```

Your business layer can now just read the configuration and form a path to the expected file:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(this.configuration.DataFolder, "test.txt");
```

Comment: I took a look at [link](http://blogengine.codeplex.com),in BlogEngine.Core/Utils.cs/line203. It uses web.config to deal with virtual path. Seems this is the only way to do it. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found a way, but I am not sure it is nice:

check `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath == "/"`

Comment: I thought you said you couldn't reference `System.Web`.

Comment: @Jacob yes, this code is in web layer. I will send different path value to the business layer depends on if(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath == "/"). it wasn't nice i think.

Comment: @EdiWang: or you could make a static variable somewhere, and set this value when the web start... Anyway thanks for the answer, it helps me.